# What is the best method to convert a pdf file to word document that contains both English and Arabic letters

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, conversion

I have this pdf file

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/thhjvtlzebe20ab/AADVLBVntblYi4Nyi_SlXVRNa?dl=0

which contains English and Arabic language. I want to convert it to .docx file and there are many ways but none of them give excellent results.

- If I open the pdf file using MS Office 2016 I get the right formatting and all Arabic letters are converted correctly. But I lose almost every shape/drawings that are in the document.
- If I convert the pdf file to .docx file I get all the shapes/drawings but then I get a bunch of page breaks, section breaks, column breaks etc. and in addition 70% of the Arabic words are not converted correctly.
- I can get rid of the breaks using a VBA code and I can repair most of the bad converted Arabic words using another code but there are still many words left where I have to correct them manually.
- Using google docs gives a bunch of mess.
- Using Abbyy finereader also results in a mess of words.

Some useful information:

- This file was created using MS Office word 2013. I lost the original files because my hard drive broke and only did backup the pdf files. Everything has the same font which is (times new roman)

Edit: I used adobe acrobat pro to convert from pdf to .docx file

If I just copy and paste the Arabic words from pdf to word document using the paste option " keep text only " I get almost perfect results. But I have over 250 pages and this will consume time that I don't have.

Comment: Sorry to say, I don't think there would be a better tool for conversion. As you already described all methods comes with a price. It seems you're familiar with macros; maybe you can create one which loops through the version with the Arabic words right and copies them to the one with right formatting, replacing the wrongly formatted words.

Comment: That is a very smart approach but I don't know to achieve this. I have only basic understanding in macros. Using different programs to convert the file results in different layout. I forgot to mention that I used adobe acrobat pro dc latest version to convert from pdf to .docx file.

Answer (score 1):

I try out this online converter https://pdf2doc.com/it/

Convert the file from PDF to DOC and open it with libreoffice give a acceptable result (mostly seems to have only pagination to be adjusted).

here the result: https://1drv.ms/f/s!Aj15LBU4peCjmZZp1BZZ7l9hwC3cqg

anyway the conversion cannot be done at 100% due the MS proprietary format of Office suite, for this reason if you use third party converter at last you loose the format, open the doc I provide you with libreoffice with word 2016 the result is not so good.

a screenshot of the doc file opened from libreoffice and word 2016:

[image]

Comment: This is a nice approach. Only problem is that all the Arabic words are messed up. The first letter is now the last letter and vice versa.  For example this English word:    "letter" -> "rettel"  This what happens in your file. This can be solved using a Macro. Right?

Comment: Edit: Not all the words are messed up.  On the first examination I think about 30% of the words are messed up.

Comment: It could be fixed by a macro, what I think is append is the converter when realize is Arabic set the write from right to left but it is not precise as a human; you could try with different tools and get a bit better result, but getting a conversion out of the box I think is not realizable.